# JSF FileUploadEvent getSource what kind of Object?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

When I get my `FileUploadEvent event` event, it is possible to extract the source object via `.getSource()`. I debugged it and I know it contains the id of `rich:fileUpload`. So I want to use the same listener for several fileUploads and need to switch this objects id. But what kind of Object is it, so I can acces this member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) and the ID is available by `getId()`. You can easily figure the exact class by looking at its `getClass()`.